# How to change the primary color of the app from app's UI in React JS(Next JS) using tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Let say the primary color of every button is `bg-gray-600` and i wanted to change it to `bg-indigo-600`. I tried using the template literals but it has no effect on UI.

```
const mycomponent = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('blue');

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setColor('gray');
        }}
      >
        Change color to gray
      </button>{' '}
      <div className={`bg-${color}-600 p-2`}> Hello world </div>{' '}
    </>
  );
};
```

The above code did changed the class but the color didnt changed, however when apply the class `bg-gray-600` as it is without the template strings , then it works, what am i missing?

Comment: Yup it does answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using full class names like:

  ```
  const mycomponent = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState('bg-blue-600');

    return (
      <>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setColor('bg-gray-600');
          }}
        >
          Change color to gray
        </button>{' '}
        <div className={`${color} p-2`}> Hello world </div>{' '}
      </>
    );
  };
  ```
- Adding the class names to [`safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes):

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    …
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^bg-(red|gray|blue)-600$/ },
    ],
    …
  }
  ```

Comment: It worked ! by adding class as <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>,. Thanks for the detailed explanation.